# How to load image by XSL FO

Tags: java, jboss, xsl-fo

I would like to load image by XSL FO and generate it by Apache FOP. I use jboss4, 2 files xsl fo and image are put in jboss/server/conf/resources/.

```
<fo:external-graphic
    src="url(\Logo.jpg)"
    content-height="scale-to-fit" height="1.00in" content-width="1.00in"
    scaling="non-uniform" />
```

The Apache FOP generate PDF without image and show the message: ERROR [FOUserAgent] Image not found. URI: . (No context info available). How I correct it?

Answer (score 2):

I am using the following

```
<fo:block font-weight="normal" text-align="left">
        <fo:external-graphic src="url(file:images/CompanyLogo.png)" content-height="8mm" />
</fo:block>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, src="url(file:images/CompanyLogo.png)" does not work for me.

Comment: well it wouldn't, unless your file is called CompanyLogo.png and it is location in the images directory.  I think the key thing here is using `file:`

Comment: I've tried with: src="url(file:Logo.png)", src="url(file:../resources/Logo.png)", (file:resources/Logo.png)". But I'm not lucky. XSL and Image files I've put in same folder resources. And I use Apache FOP to generate PDF file by DATA -> XSL FO -> PDF.

Comment: I am also using it for PDF generation.  What directory is your xsl file in?

Comment: xsl ang png files are in same folder conf/resources

Answer (score 0):

From https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/faq.html#MalformedURL:

> A relative file URL starts with anything but a slash, and doesn't have the file: prefix

and

> only forward slashes are used, even on windows.

From https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.1/configuration.html, the default for relative URIs is relative to the current directory.

If you are using a config file for FOP (https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.1/embedding.html#config-external) you should check to see if it's setting the base directory.