# Image not Found- XSL-FO

Tags: xml, xsl-fo

XSL-Fo can't retrieve my image though I've set the correct path to the image.

```
<fo:external-graphic src="../graphics/bullet.png" content-height="0.5cm" />
```

I received this error on each attempt the file was processed via Windows's command prompt.

```
org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
SEVERE: Image not found. URI: bullet.png. (See position 26:80)
org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent                                                       
SEVERE: Image not found. URI: bullet.png. (No context info available)
org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
```

The source path is the exact format provided by APACHE's FOP image example. I even executed their "image.fo" file on rendering external graphics, and still encountered the error above(with different image file).

Are there alternative solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Relative URIs are relative to the base URI (https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/fo.html#external-resources).

If you're not setting the base URI in your FOP config, the base URI is the current directory (https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.1/configuration.html).

Where is the image file relative to the directory in which you're running FOP?

---

Does it work when you use:

```
<fo:external-graphic src="examples/fo/graphics/bullet.png" content-height="0.5cm" />
```

?

Comment: Relative path to my image file:"examples\fo\graphics".

Comment: XML-FO is still unable to retrieve the image using that path.

Comment: Then firstly try putting in the absolute path: `file:///C:/.../examples/fo/graphics/bullet.png` so FOP has no choice about where to find the file.  Secondly, try running with `-x` or `-d` (https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/running.html) and see if either gives you enough information to see where FOP thinks it's running from.

Comment: I've managed to get it to work now with that path now. Thanks!

Comment: Can you still run it again using `-x` or `-d` to get FOP's idea of the base URI and try to get the relative path working?  This is the second time in a week that relative paths with FOP has come up (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26155275/how-to-load-image-by-xsl-fo), so I'd like to know what the relative path should be.

Answer (score 1):

My external-graphic tag looked like this:

```
<fo:external-graphic content-height="15.73mm" src="url('logo.png')"/>
```

and I had to put the logo.png file in the same directory as the xsl file.

That is, my fop command looked like this:

```
$TOOLS/fop-2.0/fop -d -x -xml xmlfiles/xmlfile.xml -xsl xslfiles/xslfile.xsl -pdf pdffiles/pdffile.pdf
```

and I had to put the .png file in the xmlfiles directory.

I am bringing that up because the accepted answer says the URI is the "current directory".

Answer (score 0):

As Micheal Potter figured out in https://stackoverflow.com/a/36521536/12227050 the path is relative to the xml file's URI (if there's no other base path configuration). If you cannot ensure a relation between xml file and the graphics file, you have to use a trick:

The image paths are relative to the primary xml input file. So the trick is to have a quasi empty dummy xml file as primary file near the images on the one hand and access all data from a secondary file on the other hand.

Example:

**convert.bat**

Mind that data.xml is also resolved relative to dummy.xml, so it's `../data.xml`

```
call %dir%/fop -xml script/dummy.xml -xsl script/small.xsl -pdf small.pdf -param doc3node ../data.xml
```

**data.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<C attr="Attribute here.">
    <d>Hello!</d>
    <DDDD>Dadadadam</DDDD>
</C>
```

**script/dummy.xml**

This file can probably be even more empty

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a><B></B></a>
```

**script/logo.gif**

```
[not shown here]
```

**script/small.xsl**

Mind that logo.gif is relative to dummy.xml (both reside in the same directory). The main trick is that the secondary xml file's data is basically accessed with `document('../data.xml')//element`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions" extension-element-prefixes="func">
    <xsl:param name="doc3node" select="''"/>
    <xsl:variable name="d3" select="document($doc3node)" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="DIN-A4" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm">
                    <fo:region-body margin-top="1.5cm" margin-bottom="1.5cm" margin-left="2cm" margin-right="2cm"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="DIN-A4">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <xsl:variable name="doc2node" select="'../data.xml'" />
                    <xsl:for-each select="document($doc2node)//*">
                        <xsl:call-template name="ListThemAll" />
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <fo:block><xsl:text>... again ...</xsl:text></fo:block>
                    <xsl:for-each select="$d3//*">
                        <xsl:call-template name="ListThemAll" />
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:call-template name="End"/>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="ListThemAll" match="*">
        <fo:block><xsl:text>Element: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></fo:block>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="End">
        <fo:block text-align="center">
            <fo:external-graphic src="logo.gif" content-width="2.5cm"/>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Resulting pdf file output**

```
Element: C
Element: d
Element: DDDD
... again ...
Element: C
Element: d
Element: DDDD
                                        [Centered image]
```

Comment: (Using Apache FOP 2.2)